# How to enable MessageDrivenContext injection?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, message-driven-bean

I'd like to explicity set a transaction to rollback in a JavaEE MDB:

```
private MessageDrivenContext context;
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/ReaderQueue", activationConfig =  {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(
            propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", 
            propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(
            propertyName = "destinationType", 
            propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
    })
public class MessageReaderBean implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        ctx.setRollbackOnly(); // <-- see here, my good fellow!
    }
    public void setMessageDrivenContext(MessageDrivenContext ctx) throws EJBException {
        this.context = ctx;
    }
}
```

However the container does not call `setMessageDrivenContext` for me and I get a `NullPointerException`. What magic sauce do I need to get the context injected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to also implement `javax.ejb.MessageDrivenBean` before it would recognise that callback method. (Even though it was functioning as a legitimate MDB without that interface).

Comment: That's not needed if you use annotations.

Answer (score 7):

You should annotate the MessageDrivenBeanContext with @Resource:

```
@Resource private MessageDrivenContext context;
```

Then the context will be injected by the container. You don't need the `setMessageDrivenContext` method.